# PHP How to prevent $_POST from HTML form with given id of the section

Tags: php, html, post

I have this piece of code:

```
<form action = "save.php" method = "post" onsubmit = "return submitForm()">
<tbody id = "foo">
<input type="text" name="inputField" id="inputField" value = "<?php echo $someValue ?>">
</tbody>
<input type="submit" value="Save configuration" />
</form>
```

My question is: How to prevent submitting variable $someValue to save.php page?

I tried with JS:

```
 document.getElementById("inputField").readOnly = true; 
 document.getElementById("inputField").disabled = true;
```

Which disables the field, yet does not prevent from submitting content of the input field.

Comment: Because `submitForm` takes value and send it?

Comment: I forgot to say, I need to prevent whole section id = "foo" from submitting, not only id = "inputField".

Comment: What does `submitForm()` do?

Comment: put disabled there  <tbody disabled>

Comment: remove the name attribute from the input fields.

Comment: what conditions do you want the submit to work or not work? If the user will never submit data why have a submit?

Comment: Please, imagine there are other <tbody> sections inside form, which I want to send.

Comment: We'll need to see the code in your `submitForm()` function - for all we know that could just loop through all your input fields, grab their values and stick them into an Ajax post request ... thus sidestepping whatever you do with the form attributes (e.g. `disabled`)

Comment: Why do you add form field to a form when you don't want to use them as form fields?

Comment: Thank you, it appeared that submitForm() was setting disabled to 0. Silly me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all `name` attribute from your foo section.

By example

```
<tbody id="foo">
    <input type="text" id="thisInputWillNotBeSubmited1" value = "<?php echo $someValue ?>">
    <input type="text" id="thisInputWillNotBeSubmited2" value = "<?php echo $someOtherValue ?>">
</tbody>
```

Or if you prefer jQuery (after your DOM is loaded)

```
$("#foo > input").each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr( "name" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function() {

    $("input[name='inputField']").remove();

});
```